# How to prevent discount in Acumatica?

Tags: cloud, erp, acumatica

I create  Invoice by call graph, I want my invoice does not apply discount. Do we have tips to do that by code?

Thank everyone.

Answer (score 0):

TRY [Not tested]

The following code in your extension will help you to disable the discount feature for the invoice screen.

```
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual void RecalculateDiscounts(PXCache sender, ARTran line, Action<PXCache, ARTran> del)
    {
        //Dont call del here to disable discount
        //OR call del, only certain conditions matches to enable discount
    }
```

Comment: I am creating invoice by call graph not really extension, I am sorry for wrong description in question

Comment: anyway, add this to your invoiceEntryExtension. This will *always* disable the discount in the invoice document 'i believe'.

Answer (score 0):

usually we call base method for UI but not for import, please look at the next approach

```
public class SOOrderEntryExtension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual void RecalculateDiscounts(PXCache sender, SOLine line, Action<PXCache, SOLine> del)
    {
        if (!Base.IsImport) del(sender, line);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for configuration for not doing customization.